# IE Edge Angular 1.0.3 vs 1.2.0 not showing results JSON Feed

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have 2 plunks using the same json feed from TrustPilot but one is using 1.2.0 and the other is using 1.0.3

Currently my project is using Angular 1.2.0 which the feed works on all browsers except IE 11(funny that it does work on IE10 and below). When IE 11 is being used nothing populates and I also get no error messages.

But when I switch Angular to 1.0.3 it does work on IE 11 and below.

I am curious to know why this happens and can I get this to work in IE 11 using 1.2.0 and with my current logic.

[Plnkr using 1.2.0](http://plnkr.co/edit/NBkNMm3pJ3IkoBnP5oqV?p=preview) - (doesnt work in IE11)

[Plnkr using 1.0.3](http://plnkr.co/edit/AoHTCYAzzAb3jy40z84k?p=preview) - (does work in IE11 and here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jamesmarkcook/zv6qH/) to where the code came from originally)

Note: Please don't answer saying I should use

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work in IE11 with AngularJS 1.2.0 is due to a bug.

It was fixed in AngularJS **1.2.2**.

You can read more about it in the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-122-consciousness-inertia-2013-11-22) by visiting the links next to the following section:

> **$httpBackend:** only IE8 and below can't use script.onload for JSONP

Basically in IE11 the internal API was changed and no longer uses the `onreadystatechange` event, like the previous IE versions.

The reason it works with AngularJS 1.0.3 and IE11 is just a lucky side effect.

The browser sniffer in AngularJS 1.0.3 doesn't detect the IE version properly, probably because IE11 wasn't released yet when that Angular version was developed.

This leads to that in the following code (from 1.0.3) the else block will be executed instead of the `msie` one:

```
if (msie) {
 script.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (/loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState)) doneWrapper();
 };
} else {
 script.onload = script.onerror = doneWrapper;
}
```

And since in IE11 the use of `onreadystatechange` was replaced with `onload` - it will work.

The easiest solution is to upgrade AngularJS from **1.2.0** to **1.2.2**.